# What does executorRunTime consist of in Spark?

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, metrics

Currently working on Spark, I collected some performance metrics through the custom Spark listener API for analysis purposes. I tried to make a stacked bar plot that shows the percentage of the time the executor passes executing the task, shuffling or in garbage collection pauses for three different machine learning algorithms.
Here is a screenshot of what I found:

[image: execution, garbage-collection, serialization and shuffling rates in Spark MlLib]

What caught my attention right after the plot appeared is that the rates are false. You can see that it goes beyond the value 1 for the kmeans algorithm, and less than 0.8 for the perceptron.

Here is how I computed the rates:

```
execution['cpuRate'] = execution['executorCpuTime'] / execution['executorRunTime']
execution['serRate'] = execution['resultSerializationTime'] / execution['executorRunTime']
execution['gcRate'] = execution['jvmGCTime'] / execution['executorRunTime']
execution['shuffleFetchRate'] = execution['shuffleFetchWaitTime'] / execution['executorRunTime']
execution['shuffleWriteRate'] = execution['shuffleWriteTime'] / execution['executorRunTime']

execution = execution[['cpuRate', 'serRate', 'gcRate', 'shuffleFetchRate', 'shuffleWriteRate']]

execution.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

I use Pandas library and execution is the dataframe containing the averaged metrics.
Of course, my assumption is that the executorRunTime is a summation of the underlying other metrics, but it turns out to be false.

What are the meaning of those times, and how are they correlated? I mean: what does the executorRunTime consist of if not all the other metrics specified above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to [TaskMetrics.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/TaskMetrics.scala#L71):

```
  * Time the executor spends actually running the task (including fetching shuffle data).
  */
def executorRunTime: Long = _executorRunTime.sum
```

Measured in miliseconds.