# What is the main difference between executorRunTime and executorCpuTime in apache spark. Does executorRunTime includes executorCpuTime

Tags: apache-spark

What is the main difference between **executorRunTime** and **executorCpuTime** in apache **spark**. Does executorRunTime includes executorCpuTime also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55123896/what-does-executorruntime-consist-of-in-spark

Answer (score 2):

The difference appears to boil down to the timer implementation used to measure the start and end times of a task (which is summed up for a whole job's executor or CPU runtime metrics), and the way they are computed looks very consistent, see below.

At a higher level, CPU Time more directly measures the amount of time a task actually took to execute, as it does not include time spent in other threads, whereas executor time will just count all time that passes while a task computes, including time spent in other threads. As a result, CPU runtime may be less.

See how the finish times are set and used in [executor.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/Executor.scala#L533-L556) (start times are set similarly):

```scala
val taskFinishNs = System.nanoTime()
val taskFinishCpu = if (threadMXBean.isCurrentThreadCpuTimeSupported) {
   threadMXBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime
} else 0L

// ... other code omitted for brevity ...

task.metrics.setExecutorRunTime(
  (taskFinish - taskStart) - task.executorDeserializeTime
)
task.metrics.setExecutorCpuTime(
  (taskFinishCpu - taskStartCpu) - task.executorDeserializeCpuTime
)
```

source: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/executor/Executor.scala#L533-L556