# Why spark's event log shows a great difference between executorRunTime and executorCpuTime

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068435/what-is-the-main-difference-between-executorruntime-and-executorcputime-in-apach) I understand executorRunTime is the total run time and executorCpuTime is cpu time of the total run time. From practice, I find executorRunTime almost equals `Finish Time - Launch Time`, it seems that if executorCpuTime if 10% of executorRunTime, then the work is not cpu-bound because cpu only take 10% of the total run time, and want to find what causes the rest 90% of total run time.

For example, given the following event log, I find cpu time composes only 45% of the total run time, and there is no sign of the rest 55% being consumed by GC or shuffle RW. Seems the only reason in the input is very big or may persisted, so it cost a lot of time to read. Is this true?

```
    "Task Metrics": {
        "Executor Deserialize Time": 134,
        "Executor Deserialize CPU Time": 117917324, // 118 ms
        "Executor Run Time": 41072,
        "Executor CPU Time": 18861731954, // 18861 ms
        "Result Size": 1864,
        "JVM GC Time": 222, // 222 ms
        "Result Serialization Time": 0,
        "Memory Bytes Spilled": 0,
        "Disk Bytes Spilled": 0,
        "Shuffle Read Metrics": {
            "Remote Blocks Fetched": 0,
            "Local Blocks Fetched": 0,
            "Fetch Wait Time": 0,
            "Remote Bytes Read": 0,
            "Remote Bytes Read To Disk": 0,
            "Local Bytes Read": 0,
            "Total Records Read": 0
        },
        "Shuffle Write Metrics": {
            "Shuffle Bytes Written": 59,
            "Shuffle Write Time": 721346, // 0.72 ms
            "Shuffle Records Written": 1
        },
        "Input Metrics": {
            "Bytes Read": 20384901,
            "Records Read": 222424
        },
        "Output Metrics": {
            "Bytes Written": 0,
            "Records Written": 0
        },
        "Updated Blocks": []
    }
```

However then I find the following event log, in which cpu time composes only 1% of the total run time, GC and Shuffle RW are even less. This time, there are no inputs or outputs, so my previous assumption no longer stands in this case. What may compose the rest of total run time in this case? What else can I do to have a general strategy to identify which costs a lot time suppose I have no access to source code?

```
    "Task Metrics": {
        "Executor Deserialize Time": 26,
        "Executor Deserialize CPU Time": 19948524, // 20ms
        "Executor Run Time": 198046,
        "Executor CPU Time": 1931695426, // 1931ms
        "Result Size": 1245,
        "JVM GC Time": 172,
        "Result Serialization Time": 0,
        "Memory Bytes Spilled": 0,
        "Disk Bytes Spilled": 0,
        "Shuffle Read Metrics": {
            "Remote Blocks Fetched": 0,
            "Local Blocks Fetched": 1,
            "Fetch Wait Time": 0,
            "Remote Bytes Read": 0,
            "Remote Bytes Read To Disk": 0,
            "Local Bytes Read": 1197508,
            "Total Records Read": 2903
        },
        "Shuffle Write Metrics": {
            "Shuffle Bytes Written": 0,
            "Shuffle Write Time": 0,
            "Shuffle Records Written": 0
        },
        "Input Metrics": {
            "Bytes Read": 0,
            "Records Read": 0
        },
        "Output Metrics": {
            "Bytes Written": 0,
            "Records Written": 0
        },
        "Updated Blocks": []
    }
```